# Load Insubstantial Swing Plugins to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, substance

How do I load the Insubstantial Swing plugins to Eclipse?

I refer to the plugins here: http://insubstantial.posterous.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Builder allows you to apply any look and feel you want. So, you should be able to add Substance:

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/preferences/swing/preferences_lookandfeel.html

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you may still have to do some customization in code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to copy the jars into your project and add them to the build path (under "Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries"). If you want to use them in several projects and configure the source and javadoc attachments only once, then you might want to define a User Library for them (See the "Add Library" button on that same page).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. How can I view these plugins in design view? It's extremely painful to be meddling with these things in the code view.

Comment: By "design view" I'm assuming you mean a WYSIWYG UI editor for Swing. I don't think the default Eclipse install has one - are you using a plugin like JFormDesigner?

Comment: Yes, i believe it should be called the WYSIWYG UI editor. I'm using the Windows Builder plugin in Eclipse, and would like to add the insubstantial's plugins onto the palette.